# History and egrep in one script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, grep

I have to type:

```
history | egrep ssh
```

everytime I want to search for my latest ssh connections.

Then I got an Idea, how about putting it all together in one script. I call this `histgrep.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
history | /bin/egrep "$1"
```

but, everytime I call `histgrep.sh ssh`, it won't produce any result.

Can anyone help me fix it? Or do you have alternative solution?

Comment: Don't use the `history` command at all. Use ssh tab completion to complete hostnames and use `ctrl-r` then type `ssh` and keep hitting `ctrl-r` until you find the history entry you want and hit `enter`.

Comment: Well, sometimes you put a sequence of commands like `git commit` then `git push -u origin --all`. It's not really productive to use `ctrl-r`. It just really hard for my mental image.

Comment: After you use `ctrl-r` to find the first command in the sequence don't hit `enter`. Hit `ctrl-o` then you'll execute the first command in the sequence and have the next command put on the command line for you already. Just keep hitting `ctrl-o` until you are done with the sequence.

Comment: You might want to look at this Q&A:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script

Comment: Any particular reason that you insist on using `ctrl-r`? I use it whenever I do my daily task, but for several days or weeks ago, I tend to use `history | egrep`.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Works like a charm! But, returning number is not a history event, so you can't call `!number` from the resulting script. Oh well..

Comment: after researching, I found that using `history` in a script is futile. I'll go with @EtanReisner advice and go on with my life. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `history` command works with your current shell's context, so calling it from a script will not (trivially) work.  A shell function does have access to the current shell's context, so adding something like this to your `.bashrc` or similar will do what you want.

```
histgrep () { history | egrep "$@"; }
```

An alias would technically also work, but there are usually no good reasons to prefer an alias over a function.

Answer (score 1):

Converting back to answer the (trivial) answer auto-converted to comment :)

History is by default disabled in non-interactive bash shells but can be re-enabled, see this Q&A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script

True, using `!<num>` from the script itself won't work, but in the shell calling the script (the apparent intended usage context from the question) it works just fine:

```
> cat histgrep.sh 
#!/bin/bash
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
history | egrep "$1"
> ./histgrep.sh 'ls -la'
...
  460  ls -la *
> !460
ls -la *
-rw-rw-r--. 1 userid at    24167 Nov 21  2012 cfu
-rwxrwxr-x  1 userid at       73 Jul 10 00:23 histgrep.sh
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 userid users  2025 Apr  2  2013 same_file.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 userid at      385 Jun 25 13:01 tst.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 userid at      310 Jul  9 23:58 tst.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, use bash alias.

On terminal, type:

```
alias histgrep="history | grep"
```

how to use:

```
histgrep ssh
```

above command is equal to `history | grep ssh`

Reference:

[An Introduction to bash aliases and functions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-useful-bash-aliases-and-functions)

Comment: As always, a function is probably better than an alias.  `histgrep () { history | egrep "$@"; }`

Comment: If you'd answer this, I'll choose your answer. Apparently, I had to wait for 2 days to accept my answer. This question should not stay longer on `unanswered` section.